# Output of finding prime numbers between given range does not come as expected

Tags: java, arrays

> Given two numbers n1 and n2 as input, count the primesnos containing all the primes between n1 and n2.

**MyApproach**

I took 2 for loops.For each element from start to stop I checked whether the elements are prime or not and incremented their count.

```
public int getPrimes(int start,int stop)
{

  int countprime=0;
  boolean b1=true;
  for(int j=start;j<=stop;j++)
  {
      for(int i=2;i<=j/2;i++)
      {
          if(j%i==0)
          {
              b1=false;
              break;
          }
      }
      if(b1==true)
      countprime++;
  }

 return countprime;

 }

 Parameters         Actual Output   Expected Output

 '6,11'                  0           2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to reset value of variable `b1`

```
b1 = true;
```

**Code**

```
public static int getPrimes(int start, int stop) {
        int countprime = 0;
        boolean b1 = true;
        for (int j = start; j <= stop; j++) {
            b1 = true;
            for (int i = 2; i <= j / 2; i++) {
                if (j % i == 0) {
                    b1 = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (b1 == true)
                countprime++;
        }
        return countprime;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For each value of `j` from the outer loop, you need to re-initialize `b1 = true`. Because whenever you found `j` is not prime, you set your flag `b1` to `false` and you **never reset it**. So if `j` is a prime for any next iteration, `if (b1 == true)` will not find a *true* path as `b1` is already set to `false`. Hence, `countprime` is not going to increment.

So do the following:

```
for(int j=start;j<=stop;j++)
  {
      b1 = true;
      for(int i=2;i<=j/2;i++)
      //rest of your codes...
```

---

**Side note:** Instead of `i <= j/2`, `i <= sqrt(j)` can make your code more faster! Besides, you may also read [Sieve of Atkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin).

Comment: Thank you Sir for the reference.My first approach is to solve problems and then I will move towards more faster code.